# Do opportunity attacks have disadvantage if I use my action to Dodge and then move out of melee range?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, opportunity-attack, dodge

I am currently playing a multi-class Cleric 5 / Rogue 2 and at times I have managed to kite melee mobs successfully using my *Cunning Action* to Disengage, then my movement and then using a ranged attack, which has worked fine for most of the time. Sometimes though I get pounced on by several melee mobs at once (3-5), especially when we face tactical mobs. In this case I have ended up in a loop where they catch up with me each time because I am having to use my *Cunning Action* to Disengage, instead of Dash.

Sometimes, I just want to get away quite far by using Dash instead, without getting pummeled by the opportunity attacks in the process. I want to get more distance between me and the mobs so they cannot catch up with me in their next move, i.e. to avoid melee attacks/damage before I get my next turn.

Basically, I want to be able to use **Dodge** as my Action so that when I move out of melee range from the 3-5 mobs there is less of a chance the mobs will hit me in the process, with 3-5 opportunity attacks.
We've not tried this in our campaign yet, so I want some confirmation about how this works and whether the 3-5 melee mobs who are right next to me would get **disadvantage** on their opportunity attacks as I try to dash off?

I especially appreciate answers that contain play-tested experience from DMs who have managed this situation or players who have actually played as a Rogue.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110589/discussion-on-question-by-senmurv-do-opportunity-attacks-have-disadvantage-if-i).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The description of the [Dodge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Dodge) action states:

> Until the start of your next turn, **any attack roll made against you** has disadvantage if you can see the attacker, and you make Dexterity saving throws with advantage.

Opportunity attacks require attack rolls, so they would all have disadvantage, as long as the attackers were not invisible.

That being said, I would recommend using the [Disengage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Disengage) action instead:

> If you take the Disengage action, your movement doesn't provoke opportunity attacks for the rest of the turn.

Now, instead of disadvantage, your opponents can’t make an opportunity attack against you at all.

Dodge and Disengage both use an action. So you could do either of those for your action and still dash with your bonus action. So Disengage would likely be better than Dodge, unless there’s a possibility of getting attacked from range by other enemies; in that case, Dodge might be helpful for imposing disadvantage on those ranged attacks, unless you remember this clever trick: [*ranged attacks have disadvantage against a prone target*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Prone).

You Disengage with your action, then Dash as a bonus action and get 60 feet away from your melee attackers. Then, if there are no more melee attackers within 30-40 feet of you, drop prone, and all ranged attacks will have disadvantage. When your turn comes back around, stand up (by spending movement equal to half your speed), and then Dash with both your action and bonus action for 75 feet of movement.

Answer (score -3):

## Dodge and disengage aren't enough to escape

Dodge imposes disadvantage on all attacks against you until your next turn. But that doesn't give you much benefit in this case.

If disengage/dodge, then dash and move 60ft, you will end up 60ft from where you started, with the enemies dashing right next to you once again.

You cannot win this way.

### How to escape

Here are my tactics for escaping from a melee enemy. Assuming the enemy starts right next to you:

- Double dash and eat the attacks. This is obvious, but sometimes it's the best you can do. Just get out of there. This works best if you do it before there's 5 baddies beating on you.
- Use cunning action to Disengage, then move 30ft away. Ready an action to move 30ft away when an enemy attacks you (eat an opportunity attack). That way the enemy will waste their action trying to attack you, only to have you run 30ft away. Now they have no dash action to chase you, so you can double dash on your next turn. Remember to hold your reaction until the last of them attacks!
- Use the environment. Climb up a ladder then kick it away from the wall. Cross a rope bridge then cut it loose. Use a stack of crates to climb onto a roof then push them over.
- Use skill checks. Climb and make a good climb check. Jump and make a good strength check. Balance across a difficult path and make a good dexterity check.
- Use spells or abilities. Mold Earth can create difficult terrain. Shape water can create some ice for you to step on (or freeze something you just swam through). Create bonfire and booming blade can discourage pursuit. Use gust to push your pursuer off a ledge.
- Use careful movement. If you run down a 5ft wide corridor, then only 1 enemy can effectively pursue you. If you manage to weave past obstacles you can force enemies to drop back one at a time.